# Performance differents when using parameter or constants in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, query-performance

I have a performance problem.

First PL/SQL (most time never ends and OS database process is always over 90%):

```
DECLARE 
  myId nvarchar2(10) := '0;WF21izb0';
BEGIN
  insert into MY_TABLE (select * from MY_VIEW where ID = myId);
END;
```

Second PL/SQL (ends with successfull result in 50s):

```
BEGIN
  insert into MY_TABLE (select * from MY_VIEW where ID = '0;WF21izb0');
END;
```

---

```
select count(*) from MY_VIEW
```

is also a not ending call, there are a lot of table joins behind this view.

```
select count(*) from MY_VIEW where ID = '0;WF21izb0'
```

ends in 50s with count=60000.

Can somebody explain me the reason why my first PL/SQL is not finishing after 50s? What is the difference between using static string and declared parameter?

Comment: I recommend you trace it and then profile the trace file. You'll probably get dozens of people saying the execution plan is different but they would be *only* highly educated guesses. If you get into the habit of looking correctly (trace + profile), then you'll be able to solve problems more quickly.

Comment: Are statistics up-to-date on the tables underlying the view? `SELECT LAST_ANALYZED, NUM_ROWS FROM DBA_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE'`, and compare `NUM_ROWS` to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE`. If LAST_ANALYZED is NULL or out of date, or NUM_ROWS differs significantly from the actual row counts, analyze the table with DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS.

Comment: I'm not sure whether @jeff6times7 would count this as a highly educated guess but it seems likely that (1) your view projects an enormous number of rows and (2) there is a tremendous skew in the volumes of `ID`. Given a literal value of `ID` the optimizer can come up with a custom plan to fetch those records. But given a blind variable it uses whatever plan it already has: that plan might be optimised for a value of `ID` which returns say two rows; it may not be obvious but that plan might be ruinous for an `ID` which returns 60000 rows.

Comment: you may ask your DBA if `cursor_sharing` parameter is equal to `Exact` ..?

Answer (score 0):

It boils down to what the DB engine knows about your data and your query, when preparing the query execution plan.

When a literal is placed in your query, it is a part of your query, so is known to the engine responsible for preparing the plan. It can take that literal value into account and decide on an execution plan, that is suitable, e.g. based on the DB data statistics (e.g. that this value is rare).

When you are using a PL/SQL variable, the actual query, for which the plan is determined, is different. It's something like:

```
insert into MY_TABLE (select * from MY_VIEW where ID = :param)
```

As you can see, the DB engine has now no information on the value, which will be used, when the query gets executed. So the best plan for such a scenario, is to prepare something, which is averagely good for most of the probable values (i.e. see what values in the DB will match this place most often, i.e. values that are prevalent).

If your data is unbalanced, and the `'0;WF21izb0'` value is rare (or even non-existent) in your data, a selective index may be used to narrow down, what needs to be processed, relatively soon in the critical parts of the execution plan. This plan will however backfire, when you'll use a value, which is all over the place - use of the index will be counter-productive. A better plan for such case may be a full table scan. Possibly the same one, which is used when executing `select count(*) from MY_VIEW`.

If you are faced with a scenario, where you do not know the filtering value upfront, you'll have to analyze the view code, and try to adjust it so it can be effectively used also for less "selective" values. You could try applying some optimizer hints to the query. You could also resign from using a view, and try your luck with a tabular function, where you can push your filtering predicates to the exact spots of the query, where they can be used most effectively.

**Edit**:
All in all, follow the advises from the question comments, and examine your execution plans and execution profile data. You should be able to find the culprit. From there it may not be obvious, what the solution is, but still, you know your data and relations much better than us.

Answer (score 0):

I was checking some traces, but after reading the comment of APC and the answer of Hilarion i end up in this solution:

`declare 
    sql_stmt  VARCHAR2(200); 
    id VARCHAR2(10) := '0;WF21izb0';
BEGIN 
    sql_stmt := 'insert into MY_TABLE (select * from MY_VIEW where ID = :1)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt using id;
END;`

This is done in 50s, and id can be now a function/procedure parameter. 
Thanks for the comments.